# What's the difference between `--repository_cache` and `--distdir`

Tags: bazel

As documented [here](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/command-line-reference.html#fetch-options), there are two flags for specifying a cache directory where Bazel can check before downloading a file from the net: `--repository_cache` and `--distdir`
What's the difference between them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both the repository cache and the distribution files directory have more extensive prose documentation in the [user guide](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/guide.html#repository-cache). The short version is the repository cache is a content-addressable cache used internally by Bazel. The distribution files directory is keyed by archive file name and expected to be completely user-provided.